# Mongoose modify/update objects inside and array

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB, and I am using mongoose for my schema. I want to update/modify a nested array from the schema, but I need help figuring out how to proceed with this.

Here is my schema :

```
const workoutSchema = new Schema(
  {
    dayName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    exercises: [
      {
        name: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        },
        sets: [
          {
            reps: {
              type: Number,
              required: true
            },
            weight: {
              type: Number,
              required: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)
```

Here is the example data :

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6394d7b173d4d862b1124ced",
        "dayName": "Push Day",
        "exercises": [
            {
                "name": "Lat Pulldown",
                "sets": [
                    {
                        "weight": 40,
                        "_id": "6394d7db73d4d862b1124cf6"
                    },
                    {
                        "weight": 45,
                        "_id": "6394d7db73d4d862b1124cf7"
                    },
                    {
                        "weight": 45,
                        "_id": "6394d7db73d4d862b1124cf8"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "6394d7db73d4d862b1124cf5"
            },
            {
                "name": "Deadlift",
                "sets": [
                    {
                        "reps": 5,
                        "weight": 65,
                        "_id": "6396e712ddd2681f1618922a"
                    },
                    {
                        "reps": 4,
                        "weight": 65,
                        "_id": "6396e712ddd2681f1618922b"
                    },
                    {
                        "reps": 4,
                        "weight": 65,
                        "_id": "6396e712ddd2681f1618922c"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "6396e712ddd2681f16189229"
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2022-12-10T19:02:09.771Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-12-12T08:32:17.996Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

**exercises** array can have multiple exercises. What I want is to first select the day (in this case **Push Day** and then add select the specific exercise (suppose **Lat Pulldown** in this case) and update
a particular set in the exercises array. I am unable to figure out this. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks for reading.

```
await WorkoutModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "exercises.sets._id": setId },
    { $set: { "exercises.$.sets": req.body } }
  )
```

I tried using this, but it's replacing the whole sets object rather than a single object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use arrayFilters as follow:

```
db.collection.update({
"dayName": "Push Day",
"exercises.sets._id": "6394d7db73d4d862b1124cf6"
},
{
$set: {
 "exercises.$[y].sets.$[x]": {
  test: 1
  }
}
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
{
  "x._id": "6394d7db73d4d862b1124cf6"
 },
{
  "y.name": "Lat Pulldown"
 }
]
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bZNgXzFTVjI)

Comment: This works, thanks. Is there some way in which I can update only the values that I am sending while keeping the old values. Suppose I have a set { reps: 4, weight: 30} and I am updating only the {weight: 35}, but this replaces the complete object, and reps is removed. Any workaround this?

Comment: you can update values only as follow: https://mongoplayground.net/p/mrcwJ3H0V8H

Answer (score 1):

To modify or update objects inside an array in Mongoose, you can use the `Model.updateMany()` method, along with the `$set` operator and the `$positional` operator. For example, if you have a model called BlogPost with a field called comments that contains an array of objects, you could use the following code to update a specific object in the array:

```
BlogPost.updateMany(
    { "comments._id": <id of the object to update> },
    { $set: { "comments.$.name": "New name" } }
)
```

In the above code, the $set operator is used to update the name field of the object in the comments array that has a matching `_id` field. The $ positional operator is used to specify which element in the comments array to update.

Alternatively, you can use the `Model.findOneAndUpdate()` method to update a single document that contains an array of objects. For example:

```
BlogPost.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "comments._id": <id of the object to update> },
    { $set: { "comments.$.name": "New name" } }
)
```

In this case, the `findOneAndUpdate()` method will find the first document that matches the query, and then update the specified object in the comments array. This method is useful if you only want to update a single document, rather than multiple documents as with the `updateMany()` method.